# How to fix 'Unable to find element with css selector' in Selenium on IE

Tags: python, selenium

I'm setting up a Selenium script on IE 11 to interact with checkboxs and radio buttons and am running into errors regarding CSS selectors not being found. I am able to get the script to log me in and navigate to the correct area using other CSS selectors.

Here is the result of Inspect Element on the checkbox that I am trying to work with.

```
<input name="AltrntProxyInd1" id="AltrntProxyInd" style="display: block; visibility: visible;" onclick="if(this.value != &quot;Y&quot;){ this.value = &quot;Y&quot;; countInstrucType(this, 'AltrntProxy' , 'Y'); } else{ this.value = &quot;N&quot;; countInstrucType(this, 'AltrntProxy' , 'N'); } fnRefreshInstructionGroup(this); if(typeof(fnChangedNotificationFunction) != &quot;undefined&quot;) { fnChangedNotificationFunction(this); }" type="checkbox" value="Y" xp2="0" xp1="Instruction" csentry="" cshidden="0" cshiddenorig="0" csentryorig="O" vo="N" CSEntryBeforeHide="O">
```

When I try and use

```
browser.find_element_by_id("AltrntProxyInd").send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```

I am given the error Unable to find element with css selector == [id="AltrntProxyInd"]

My current workaround is to use the following code, which targets a separate CSS element and then TABs down to the desired element. This is giving me the desired outcome, but I want to eliminate the tabbing and work with the element directly.

```
browser.find_element_by_id("urlAccountSpecialHandler").send_keys(Keys.TAB * 11)

AltProxyBox = browser.switch_to.active_element

time.sleep(1)

AltProxyBox.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```

Please let me know if a screenshot of the webform would be needed/helpful in diagnosing this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share the html of the element and it's parent.

Comment: It sounds like the element _actually isn't there_ at first, but is dynamically created by javascript in response to you tabbing around the page.

Comment: @supputuri html has been updated. I didn't use the code separators and it got removed from the original post.

Comment: @JohnGordon I updated my post with the html. There is some JS in there. When not using Selenium, I am able to directly click on the intended checkbox as soon as the page loads.

Comment: @Amanser, Just to make sure, can you check if your `input` element is inside any frame/iframe element?

Comment: @Kamal Here is a screenshot from the DOM https://pasteboard.co/Ima0gxTN.png. I'm new to this so please let me know if it was something else you were wanting.

Comment: @Amanser, I can't see the `input` element you are looking for in the screenshot you have shared. To be clear, I want you to check if the element you are trying to find with Selenium, is a child of `iframe/frame` element. You can find many examples of it on StackOverflow.